# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.dataTable.ext')

Tags: jquery, django, datatable

When click any category(tab) of Tabs, dataTable should remove other categories data. I follow this example - http://jsfiddle.net/d5hre2ux/ , but the system gives "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.fn.dataTable.ext')" error.

here is my code.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script>

    $('#alldataTable').DataTable({ 
    });

    var table1 = $('#alldataTable').DataTable();

    $("#Tabs").click(function(event){
    $.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var id = event.target.id;
      return $(table1.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('data-user') == id;
  }
);
table1.draw();
});   

$('#alldataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
var data = table1.row( this ).data();
window.location.href = "about"
});
```

Comment: I went to the jsfiddle you shared, I do not see any error. How to recreate the error?

Comment: seems to work, add to your reset button `table.draw(true);`

Comment: if I replace $ with Jquery word in front of function, it says cant find variable Jquery. I have included Jquery files and in order.

Comment: use noconflict like this: http://jsfiddle.net/udpfpafg/

Comment: Thanks, 'jquery.min.js' was conflicted with it, after removing, everything is fine